# C# recalling method leads to program exit

Tags: c#, recursion, menu

I've been coding a text adventure game. When the program is run, the `Boot()` method is called, reading %APPDATA%.ilan\texert for setting files (meanwhile there is only username.txt). After `Boot()`, it goes to `MainMenu()`, where the user can choose to play, go to options, or exit. When the user goes to the Options menu, and comes back, then tries to play the game or return to the options menu, the game quits, which is not supposed to happen. [Source](http://pastebin.ca/2463137)
`Boot()` = Line 455
`MainMenu()` = Line 579
`Main()` = Line 504
I believe it is because the `int` is declared in the method itself, and because the method is called multiple times the `int` variable retains its previous value. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You don't have a loop in `public static void Main()`. Put a breakpoint in this method and use step over, and you'll see what's going wrong. EDIT: That said, you seriously need to rethink your *entire* architecture...

Comment: I know my architecture sucks, I'm only a beginner.. (i have no idea how to improve my code so I do as is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At line 610 you retrieve the results of your MainMenu method, then call your OptionMenu method at line 617, but once the OptionMenu() method fires you don't do anything else to prevent your application from ending once control returns back to the Main() method. Even though you call MainMenu() in your OptionMenu() method there is nothing evaluating the results of that call so all you do is write the menu to the console and return back to Main(). You need to put a loop in the Main() method that will repeatedly call your MainMenu() method, evaluating the selected results, and other menu options like OptionMenu() will just return to this loop rather than calling the main menu themselves. Something like this:

```
string whatToDo = "null";
bool exitApp = false;
while (!exitApp)
{
    whatToDo = AdvTime.MainMenu();
    if (whatToDo.Contains("play"))
    {
        Menu("null", false);
    }
    if (whatToDo.Contains("options"))
    {
        AdvTime.OptionMenu();
    }
    if (whatToDo.Contains("exit"))
    {
        exitApp = true;
    }
    if (whatToDo.Contains("null"))
    {
        AdvTime.MMError("OM");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you update your code at pastebin I'll take another look. Ultimately everything should be returning to this loop that should cycle and call MainMenu() again until the user chooses Exit. If you have other places where you are calling Environment.Exit(), that could be circumventing this loop.

Comment: [Here it is.](http://pastebin.ca/2463151) I don't know why it isn't working, I tried putting the OptionMenu() in a while loop too, but same problem.

Comment: I was able to cut-and-paste your code and run it as-is, and it works. It's a bit confusing though, because in `OptionMenu()` you call `MainMenu()` which blocks until you enter a menu item but then returns to the main loop which calls `MainMenu()` again. I removed the call to `MainMenu()` in `OptionMenu()` and it flowed better. You should remove any place where you call `MainMenu()` but don't actually evaluate the return value (like in `MMError()`) so that all your nested method calls can complete and trickle back up to the main loop.